# Spring MVC Encoding Rest URL PathVariable

Tags: ajax, spring, rest, http, spring-mvc

I want to delete this metadata : "déééé"

I have this HTTP REQUEST :

```
DELETE /test/api/metadata/d%C3%A9%C3%A9%C3%A9%C3%A9 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8585
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:8585
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://localhost:8585/test/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: JSESSIONID=4f789...
```

I have this Mapping Controller :

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "metadata/{categoryName}", produces = "application/json", method = DELETE)
  public @ResponseBody boolean deleteMetadata(@PathVariable String categoryName) { 
      return test.deleteCategory(categoryName);
  }
```

but in my controller i get this : dÃ©Ã©Ã©Ã© so wrong **encoding**

in my web.xml i have this :

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

what is **missing** ?

Comment: you tried setting the contentType of the request to `application/json;charset=UTF-8` from your client? Just seems to me the request is messed up already before going to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoding of the URL is defined by the server. If you use Tomcat then somewhere in your `server.xml` you have the setup for the connectors. Just add the preferred encoding:

```
<Connector port="8080" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```